# Passing a JSON object from one controller to a different controller in different project

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have been trying to communicate between two CodeIgniter projects.

I have 2 projects, say A and B.  Whenever a view is called from A and it should hit the controller of project B instead of A.

I want to allow database access to only project B and not A. SO all database quires should be performed my B, and all displays should be done by A

Is there a way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "it should hit the controller of project B"?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to build some APIS, where i need to figure out a way to communicate between to projects..

Comment: Do you want to communicate from the server-side or client-side?

Comment: title, body and comments seem to say different things. WHat, _exactly_, do you want to do?

Comment: i need to figure out a way to communicate between two code igniter project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the class `CI_Loader` like this :

```
class ClassNameYouWant extends CI_Loader {
    public function construct(){ 
            parent::__construct(); 
    }

    public  function ExtendedView($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE){
        parent::view($view, $vars, $return);

        // run your code here
        // call projet B using cURL or whatever you want
    }
}
```

If you want to run your code BEFORE the view is loaded, call the line `parent::view($view, $vars, $return);` at the end of the function.

You will have to load the class inside your controller and then use something like

`$this->ClassNameYouWant->ExtendedView();`

Comment: Will this load a hit a controller from a different project?

Comment: No. This answer your question part 1 `Whenever a view is called from A`. This class extention will run everytime a view is called from A. You have to write the script now to call your other webpage using cURL, file_get_contents, whatever you want inside this function. I just gave you the way of doing this. I don't really know what you want, and I won't write thousand lines of code.

Comment: i changed the content above may be you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If CodeIgniter's MVC is similar to CakePHP's, you'll need to accept the data in controller A, then use an HTTP socket connection to Server B and transmit the data you received in Controller A to Controller B. Then Controller B can run its business logic and return (as an HTTP response) more JSON data back to your controller.

Comment: is there a way that i can redirect to the controller in the other project??